# How do we calculate the power of the cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

Let $\pi=(1\ 2)\circ (3\ 4), \ \sigma=(5 \ 6\ 7)\in \text{Sym}(7)$.

Determine a $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(\pi\circ \sigma)^n=\text{id}$.

Let $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\pi^{n!}=\text{id}$ for all $\pi\in \text{Sym}(n)$.

We have that $$\pi\circ\sigma=(1\ 2)\circ (3\ 4)\circ (5 \ 6\ 7)$$ The three cycles are disjoint, so we cannot simplify that.

Then to find that $n$ we have to caalculate all powers till we find the identity permutation, right?

Does it hold that $(\pi\circ\sigma) ^2=\pi\circ\sigma\circ \pi\circ\sigma$ ?

Comment: Yes, but that’s not what you want to do. You want to use the fact that if $\rho$ and $\tau$ commute, then $(\rho\circ\tau)^n = \rho^n\tau^n$, and use the decomposition into disjoint cycles you found.

Answer (score 1):

When $a, b\in G$ commute, and have finite order, and $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=\{e\}$ (as in this case), then $|ab|=\operatorname{lcm}(|a|, |b|)$.

So, $n=6$ is the order of$π\circ\sigma$.  So $6k$ will do, for any positive integer $k$.

For part two, use Lagrange's theorem, together with the fact that $|S_n|=n!$.

Comment: For the second question do we consider the cyclic subgroup that is generated by $\pi$? Or how do we use the Lagrange theorem?

Comment: Well this is pretty much a textbook application. You could do just that.  The subgroup $π$ generates has order $|π|$, and by the theorem divides $n!$, the order of the group.  So $n!=k|π|\implies π^{n!}=π^{k|π|}={(π^{|π|})}^k =e^k=e$.